# convert a string (HH:mm) into date and print custom formatting (arrives in x minutes)

Tags: javascript, regex, date, time, substring

i have this javascript:

```
var data = '<Message>Fermata 1494 -  Linea R2 -> 14:01  Linea 202 -> 14:06   </Message>';
var arr = data.match(/[\w\d]+\s*->\s*[\d:]+/g);
alert(arr);
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
arr[i] = arr[i].replace('->', 'at');
arr[i] = arr[i]+'\n';
}
arr = arr.join('');
console.log(arr);
```

it fetches a formatted page and prints this information:

`R2 at 14:01
202 at 14:06`

jsfiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgBc4/1/)

i need to print in

`R2 at 14:01 - arrives in x minutes` format...

so i need to convert "14:01" part of the string in current timestamp and then do a substraction but seems tha i cant do it, in pure javascript, no jquery.

Comment: What is you original time format, Date or just hh:mm (14:01)?

Comment: (date1.getMilliseconds()-date2.getMilliseconds())/(60*1000) can give difference between two timestamp in minutes.

Comment: @Danyu thanks for reply, i have just a string as i wrote above "R2 at 14:01" so i need to convert it in date format.

Comment: Be it all your woes forgotten: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be close to this. Little bit tricky, because I don't know how it rolls over on midnight.

```
function handleMessage(message) {
    var now = new Date();
    var list = message.match(/[\w\d]+\s*->\s*[\d:]+/g);
    var result = list.map(function(entry) {
        return handleEntry(entry, now);
    }).join("\n");

    alert(result);
}

function handleEntry(entry, now) {
    var parts = entry.split(" -> ");
    var line = parts[0];
    var time = parts[1];

    var minutesToGo = getMinutesToGo(time, now);

    return ("Line " + line + " arrives in " + minutesToGo + " minutes");
}

function getMinutesToGo(time, now) {
    var parts = time.split(":");
    var timeMinutes = (parseInt(parts[0]) * 60) + parseInt(parts[1]);
    var nowMinutes = (now.getHours() * 60) + now.getMinutes();
    var oneDayMinutes = 24 * 60;

    return (oneDayMinutes + timeMinutes - nowMinutes) % oneDayMinutes;
}

var message = '<Message>Fermata 1494 -  Linea R2 -> 14:01  Linea 202 -> 14:06   </Message>';

handleMessage(message);
```

Comment: this solution fits my needs very well! thanks midnight coder, your code rolls fine even at midnight!:D

Comment: Good to hear that. An upvote would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: id' love to do that but i got 9 in reputation :(

Comment: sorry to bother you again @robby but as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcz4G) for every entry it launches an alert. i want to output the string all togheter, e.g.  
Linea R2 xx minutes  
Linea R1 xx minutes  

and so on..seems i need to do an iteration but i cant find where...

Comment: thanks! now it works just perfect! when reaching 15 reputation i'll remember to upvote you!

Answer (score 0):

Assume the date is today, you can construct the date string like this:

```
var today =new Date();
var dateStr=today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()
            +" 14:01"+ ":00"; // attach hh:mm
```